# Did Leckie consult with the audiobook narrators on pronunciation?

Tags: audiobook, ann-leckie, imperial-radch

I love how Adjoa Andoh narrates the audiobook version of Ann Leckie's *Imperial Radch* trilogy, especially her pronunciation of Radchaai words and her singing. Did Leckie give Andoh those pronunciations and tunes, or did Andoh come up with them on her own?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Andoh seems to have come up with the pronunciations and tunes in the UK *Imperial Radch* audiobooks on her own. The pronunciations used by American narrator Celeste Ciulla, however, are from Leckie herself.

Ann Leckie [talks about this](http://www.annleckie.com/2015/08/07/a-brief-note-about-the-audio-versions-of-the-ancillary-books/) on her blog, where she says that she was given the opportunity to choose Andoh out of a lineup for the UK audiobooks but wasn't asked to consult with Andoh the way she did with Ciulla:

> [Recorded Books] set up a phone call with me to go over pronunciations, so Celeste Ciulla pronounces everything the way that I would. Any tunes, however, are her own and not mine–I didn’t provide music!
>   [...]
>    I love [Andoh's] voice and what I’ve heard of her reading. Nobody consulted me about pronunciations, though, so they’re different from the US one. And once again, I didn’t provide any tunes (I don’t have any, really, except for the “real” songs)[...].